# Ubuntu 22.04.1 do-release-update not working due to aufs storage driver

Tags: 22.04, docker, do-release-upgrade

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.4 and since 22.04.1 arrived today, I'd like to `do-release-upgrade` to it. In doing so I'm arriving at the following error:

```
Sorry, this storage driver is not supported in kernels for newer
releases

There will not be any further Ubuntu releases that provide kernel
support for the aufs storage driver.

Please ensure that none of your containers are using the aufs storage
driver, remove the directory /var/lib/docker/aufs and try again.
```

This appears to happen after (speculation) a new docker process is spawned, and inside it there is an `apt update` that produces this error and stops. I can then `x` out of it.

As far as I can tell I do not actually have `docker` (or is it `docker.io`?) on my Ubuntu.

How can I proceed with this upgrade?

Comment: If you are sure that you have no aufs processes, then follow the directions that you posted in your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case this error simply indicated that the remnants of a `docker` package (previously installed, but now removed) was enough to prevent the upgrade.

Removing these remnants was enough to be able to go further with the `do-release-upgrade`. Specifically, as the error says:

```
Please ensure that none of your containers are using the aufs storage
driver, remove the directory /var/lib/docker/aufs and try again.
```

I `rm`ed the `/var/lib/docker/aufs` directory.

Comment: Would be nice to know how to check if any containers do use aufs storage before removing it. Any thoughts?

Comment: This is only viable if you have no docker aufs volumes. Otherwise this will kill them. Use with caution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400479/find-to-which-container-or-image-a-docker-aufs-diff-folder-belongs-to probably helps finding if that data is necessary or not.

Comment: How did you remove the remnants? It is unclear to me.

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah I simply deleted the folder. Nothing more. `rm -rf /var/lib/docker/aufs` (ymmw, and perhaps some relevant remnants might reside in `/var/lib/docker` as well).